# Gene Expression Database for Psychological Disorders

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, data, genetics

Is there a comprehensive database available online of gene expression across the brain taken from individuals with psychological conditions? Resources like the Allen Institute's Human Brain Map (link [here](https://human.brain-map.org/microarray/search/show?search_term=52&search_type=gene_classification) for reference) feature heatmaps of gene expression taken from healthy volunteers, and I'm looking for similar datasets from patients with particular conditions, especially sensory processing disorders such as ASD and ADHD. Any and all data is appreciated!

Comment: A thought, if there's no satisfaction here we've a [bioinformatics.se] site you could try (other than biology, medical stacks).

Comment: Might be worth a shot, thanks! Is there any rule about posting the same question across multiple Stack Exchanges, though?

Comment: Best to delete this one first. If you're looking for an answer on a short timescale, weekends tend to be quiet anyhow.